# Keras sequential Modeling to Functional API

Tags: python-3.x, keras, neural-network

I am trying to convert a NN architecture made by keras sequential to functional API. However, when I do that my network learns nothing. And it's validation accuracy remains at 28%. The original code is :

https://github.com/flag0010/pop_gen_cnn/blob/master/selection/train.model.PYTHON3.py

**The NN is set up from line # 26 - 73.**

The way I've set up the NN is:

```
i1 = Input(shape=(5000, 208))

c1 = Conv1D(128*2, kernel_size=ksize,activation='relu',data_format='channels_first',kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(l2_lambda))(i1)
c1 = Conv1D(128*2, kernel_size=ksize, activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(l2_lambda))(c1)
c1 = AveragePooling1D(pool_size=ksize)(c1)
c1 = Dropout(0.2)(c1)

c1 = Conv1D(128*2, kernel_size=ksize, activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(l2_lambda))(c1)
c1 = AveragePooling1D(pool_size=ksize)(c1)
c1 = Dropout(0.2)(c1)

c1 = Conv1D(128*2, kernel_size=ksize, activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(l2_lambda))(c1)
c1 = AveragePooling1D(pool_size=ksize)(c1)
c1 = Dropout(0.2)(c1)

c1 = Conv1D(128*2, kernel_size=ksize, activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(l2_lambda))(c1)
c1 = AveragePooling1D(pool_size=ksize)(c1)
c1 = Dropout(0.2)(c1)

c1 = Flatten()(c1)

i2 = Input(shape=(5000, ))
c2 = Dense(64,  activation='relu',kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(l2_lambda))(i2)
c2 = Dropout(0.1)(c2)

c = concatenate([c1, c2])

x = Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='normal',kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(l2_lambda))(c)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
output = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model([i1, i2], [output])

model.summary()

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
                  optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

for e in range(epochs):
    for xtrainx, ytrainx, postrainx in training_data:
        print (e, xtrainx, ytrainx, postrainx)
        xtrain, ytrain,postrain = u[xtrainx], u[ytrainx], u[postrainx]
        ytrain = keras.utils.to_categorical(ytrain, num_classes)
        postrain = sequence.pad_sequences(postrain, padding='post', value=-1., dtype='float32',  maxlen=5000)
        xtrain = sequence.pad_sequences(xtrain, padding='post',  maxlen=5000)
        model.fit([xtrain, postrain], ytrain, batch_size=64,
                  epochs=1,
                  verbose=1,
                  validation_data=([xtest, postest], ytest))
```

What both of the codes are doing is that one branch of the network is a convolution neural network that takes a matrix of size 5000 x 208 as input and the other branch is a fully connected NN that takes a vector of size 5000.  I then concatenate the two branches and give it to a FC NN. On github the network is being concatenated as:

```
model.add(Merge([b1, b2], mode = 'concat'))
```

And I concatenate the two branches as:

```
c = concatenate([c1, c2])
```

My code runs absolutely fine and without errors but, my NN doesn't learn anything. Do you think it could that I am concatenating the wrong way? If so how would you concatenate using functional API? Insights would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you encounter similar problem with the original code as well?

Comment: I can not run the original code because it's deprecated. But the original code is supposed to to get upto 65% test accuracy which is why I'm thinking that maybe I'm concatenating the wrong way. But I am not aware of any other way to concatenate.

Comment: No, you are doing it correctly. I have no idea why the validation accuracy is low. Make sure that, besides the model architecture, all the other (hyper-)parameters and pre-processing are the same as to original code.

Comment: Everything is just like the original code. The only thing I changed was the way NN was set up.